# SwiftUI List row with multiple "push" style elements

Tags: swiftui

I have a design to create a tableview like row setup, where each row has a top name and a number of details in the cell. If the name is tapped, a new screen is pushed (not presented as a sheet), if the rest of the row is tapped, then another screen is pushed.
What's the best way to accomplish this?

I explored a number of ways, e.g. nesting NavigationLinks, nesting a Button within a NavigationLink (the button has a highPriorityGesture).. but no good solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
@State pushNumberView : Bool = false
@State pushNameView : Bool = false


list {
    forEach(your_array) { item in
       CellView(
           numberNavigation: $pushNumberView,
           nameNavigation: $pushNameView)
    }
}
// MARK: Navigation Links
Group{
    NavigationLink(
          destination:NameView(),
           isActive: $pushNameView
    ){EmptyView()}
                
    NavigationLink(
        destination:NumerView()
        isActive: $pushNumberView
    ){EmptyView()}     
}
```

CellView :

```
struct CellView : View {
    @Binding numberNavigation : Bool
    @Binding nameNavigation : Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("name")
           .onTapGesture{
              nameNavigation = true
           }
        Text("number")
           .onTapGesture{
              numberNavigation = true
           }
    }
}
```